# Is get(0) on java.util.List always O(1)?

Tags: java, collections, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Of my knowledge, there are the following implementations:

- ArrayList
- LinkedList
- Vector
- Stack

(based on http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html pls correct if wrong)

ArrayList is a dynamic array implementation, so, as array, get is O(1), LinkedList has O(1) for get from Head, Vector and Stack are based on ArrayList, hence, O(1).

So in EVERY case get(0) on any built-in (cause you can make your own, for a specific purpose on making get(0) TS of O(n!)) implementation of List if O(1)?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to say that `get(0)` is `O(1)`. Big O notation is for how an algorithm behaves in general, not what happens in specific cases where the algorithm runs. If you substitute `n` then *any* algorithm becomes `O(1)`. but I don't think that is really useful for analysing it or reasoning about it.

Comment: You knowledge is flawed, if you think Java only has those 4 implementations. Read the documentation, i.e. the javadoc of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html), and see the "**All Known Implementing Classes**" section at the beginning.

Comment: Next, remember that custom implementations are allowed, and you don't know how they would work, so no, you cannot definitively state that `get(0)` would **always** be _O(1)_ regardless of list size.

Comment: I try to answer but your question is not really correct.

Answer (score 3):

> Is get(0) on java.util.List always O(1)?

Let us assume that there is a parameter `N` which stands for the length of the list<sup>1</sup>.

For the 4 implementations of `List` that you mentioned, `get(0)` is indeed an `O(1)` operation:

- `ArrayList`, `Vector` and `Stack` all implement `get(i)` using array subscripting and that is an `O(1)` operation.
- `LinkedList.get(i)` involves `i` link traversals which is `O(i)`.  But if `i` is a constant, that reduces to `O(1)`.

However there are other "built in" implementations of `List`.  Indeed, there are a considerable number of them if you include the various non-public implementations, such as the `List` classes that implement sublists, unmodifiable lists, and so on.  Generalizing from those 4 to "all of them" is not sound<sup>2</sup>.

---

But `get(0)` won't be `O(1)` for all possible implementations of `List`.

- Consider a simple linked list where the elements are chained in the reverse order.  Since `get(0)` needs to traverse to the end of the list, which is `N` link traversals: `O(N)`.
- Consider a list that is *fully* populated from the rows in a database query's result set the first time that you attempt to retrieve a list element.  The first `get` call will be at least `O(N)` because you are fetching `N` rows.  (It could be worse than `O(N)` if the database query is not `O(N)`.)  So the worst case complexity for *any* call to `get` is `O(N)` ... or worse.

Indeed, with a some ingenuity, one could invent a custom list where `get(0)` has any Big-O complexity that you care to propose.

---

<sup>1 - I am being deliberately vague here.  On the one hand, we need to identify a variable `N` denoting the "problem" size for complexity analysis to make sense.  (The length of the list is the obvious choice.)  On the other hand, the length of a `List` is a surprisingly "rubbery" concept when you consider all of the possible ways to implement the interface.</sup>

<sup>2 - I assume that you are asking this question because you want to write some library code that relies on `List.get(0)` being `O(1)`.  Since you can't prevent someone from using your library with a non-builtin list implementation, your "assume it is builtin" constraint in your question doesn't really help ... even if we could check all possible (past, current or future) builtin `List` implementations for you.</sup>

Comment: please elaborate on "populated from DB"? didn't get how it relates to complexity of get(0)

Comment: Fetching N records from a database will be `O(N)`.  If you have to do that a part of the first call to `get(...)`, that makes that call `O(N)`.  And, you might even need to do it on every `get` call.  But this is just an example,  If you don't entirely understand it, look at the next one.  Or invent one for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring custom implementations, and only looking at built-in implementations, like suggested at the end of the question, you still cannot say that `get(0)` will be *O(1)* regardless of list size.

As an example, calling `get(0)` on a sublist based on a `LinkedList` will be *O(n)*:

```java
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
List<Integer> subList = list.subList(4, 8);
Integer num = subList.get(0); // <===== O(n), not O(1)
```

In that code, `subList.get(0)` internally calls `list.get(4)`, which has *O(n)* time complexity.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, for all implementations of `List` you mentioned `get(0)` is O(1).

Comment: Incorrect, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64511408/5221149).

Comment: You are using a wrong assumption in your example. If you look at the source of `LinkedList.node(int)`, you will see that in case of index being the first or last element, the for-loop only runs once, which means that `get(0)` as well as `get(size - 1)` are O(1).

Comment: But `get(0)` on a **sublist** of a `LinkedList` ends up being a `get(x)` call on the `LinkedList` itself, which is not _O(1)_, as you'd know if you actually read my answer.

Comment: Yes, but that's still not O(n), but is still O(1) from the point of algorithmic complexity. `get(4)` is a constant.

Comment: `get(4)` is an *example*. `get(0)` on the sublist becomes `get(fromIndex)` on the `LinkedList`, where `fromIndex` was the first parameter to [`subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-). With a list of size `n`, and an unspecified `fromIndex` value, the time complexity of `get(0)` on the sublist is _O(n)_, because `get(x)` is _O(n)_ when `x` is unspecified.